# MySQL subqueries multiple result

Tags: mysql, subquery

Is it possible to make the code below work. At the moment it only show employees from "New York" but not employees from "Chicago".?

```
SELECT employees.ename, zipcodes.city
FROM employees
LEFT JOIN zipcodes
ON employees.zip=zipcodes.zip
WHERE employees.zip =
(
SELECT zipcodes.zip
FROM zipcodes
WHERE zipcodes.city = 'New York' OR 'Chicago'
)
ORDER BY employees.eno;
```

Thanks in advance!

//René

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `IN` condition, like this:

```
SELECT employees.ename, zipcodes.city
FROM employees
LEFT JOIN zipcodes
ON employees.zip=zipcodes.zip
WHERE employees.zip IN
(
    SELECT zipcodes.zip
    FROM zipcodes
    WHERE zipcodes.city IN ('New York', 'Chicago')
)
ORDER BY employees.eno
```

Another approach (possibly better one) is to use the `JOIN` condition itself instead of a sub query, like this:

```
SELECT employees.ename, zipcodes.city
FROM employees
LEFT JOIN zipcodes
ON employees.zip=zipcodes.zip
AND zipcodes.city IN ('New York', 'Chicago')
ORDER BY employees.eno
```

Comment: It still just show the first result "New York" and does not take "Chicago" into account. Am I still missing something? Is there a better way to show employees that live in "New York" or "Chicago"?

Comment: @VanDerPrygel Usage of `OR` should be like this `WHERE zipcodes.city = 'New York' OR zipcodes.city = 'Chicago'`. Alternatively use the `IN` condition in the WHERE clause as well. I have updated my answer above.

Comment: I missed that you had changed the "OR" with an ",". Now it works.

Comment: But why do it this way? Does it offer some advantage over a regular join?

Comment: @Strawberry good thought. Not sure about any performance gain, however using second JOIN condition (instead of subquery) seems a better approach.

Comment: @VanDerPrygel I have updated my answer and added a possibly better approach to use.

Comment: @Aziz I have just used the updated code and it works and as you say it looks like a better solution. Thanks again!